# Wordpress Post Feature Clone

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a website. The website was running on wordpress but it is being custom redesigned because the website will be made up of 80% new features.

Is there anyway i can get the post functionalities of wordpress without using wordpress. or is there any library that can offer me the wp post feature?

Comment: Mod flags aren't for notifying us you are running out of time on your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are very complex and you need a very powerful developer to export that feature to your new CMS. But wordpress is open source and you can do whatever you want with it but with the license limits.

http://wordpress.org/download/source/

Answer (score 0):

You should continue to WordPress and modify your templates and `functions.php` as needed. 80% more features is easier than a 100% new site. Good luck to any developer trying to cook up an analog to the core WP features... its taken WP 10 years to get where it is!